# Cannot set value on more than one object

Tags: java

I have an object I created called annuals... i have getters and setters for this object and it implements comparable. When I create multiples of this object to add to a list, I end up with one object with values but all subsequent objects are have null values. How do I prevent this? Code is blow broken down by object and creating object.

Thanks in advance...

Object:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class Annuals implements Comparable<Annuals>
{

    private BigDecimal value;
    private Date dateCalculated;
    private BigDecimal dataYear;
    private String type;
    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public BigDecimal getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(BigDecimal value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    /**
     * @return the dateCalculated
     */
    public Date getDateCalculated()
    {
        return dateCalculated;
    }
    /**
     * @param dateCalculated the dateCalculated to set
     */
    public void setDateCalculated(Date dateCalculated)
    {
        this.dateCalculated = dateCalculated;
    }
    /**
     * @return the dataYear
     */
    public BigDecimal getDataYear()
    {
        return dataYear;
    }
    /**
     * @param dataYear the dataYear to set
     */
    public void setDataYear(BigDecimal dataYear)
    {
        this.dataYear = dataYear;
    }
    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    /**
     * @param type the type to set
     */
    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Annuals [value=" + value + ", dateCalculated=" + dateCalculated + ", dataYear=" + dataYear + ", type="
                + type + "]";
    }
    public static Comparator<Annuals> yearComparator = new Comparator<Annuals>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(Annuals o1, Annuals o2)
        {
            return o1.getDataYear().compareTo(o2.getDataYear());
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Annuals o)
    {
        return this.value.compareTo(o.value);
    }
}
```

Creating Object:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateCompanies
{
    private List<CompanyInfoDO> companiesList = new ArrayList<CompanyInfoDO>(); 
    /**
     * @return the companiesList
     */
    public List<CompanyInfoDO> getCompaniesList()
    {
        return companiesList;
    }

    /**
     * @param companiesList the companiesList to set
     */
    public void setCompaniesList(List<CompanyInfoDO> companiesList)
    {
        this.companiesList = companiesList;
    }

    public CreateCompanies()
    {
        CompanyInfoDO company = new CompanyInfoDO();
        company.setCompanyName("Ford");
        company.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
        company.setShares("39000000000");
        company.setTicker("f");
        company.setStockPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(11.14));
        company.setTotalOutstandingSharesAnnuals(getTotalSharesOutstandingList());
        company.setNetIncomeAnnuals(getNetIncomeList());
        companiesList.add(company);

    }

    private List<Annuals> getTotalSharesOutstandingList()
    {
        List<Annuals> annualsList = new ArrayList<Annuals>();
        Annuals annual = new Annuals();
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2013));
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(3984.0));
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING);

        Annuals annual1 = new Annuals();
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2014));
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(4009.0));
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING);

        Annuals annual2 = new Annuals();
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2015));
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(4031.0));
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING);

        Annuals annual3 = new Annuals();
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2016));
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(3931.0));
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING);

        annualsList.add(annual);
        annualsList.add(annual1);
        annualsList.add(annual2);
        annualsList.add(annual3);
        return annualsList;
    }

    private List<Annuals> getNetIncomeList()
    {
        List<Annuals> annualsList = new ArrayList<Annuals>();
        Annuals annual = new Annuals();
        annual.setDateCalculated(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.NET_INCOME);
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(11953.0));
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2013));
        System.out.println("Annual: "+ annual.toString());
        annualsList.add(annual);

        Annuals annual2 = new Annuals();
        annual.setDateCalculated(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.NET_INCOME);
        annual.setValue(new BigDecimal(1231.0));
        BigDecimal val2 = new BigDecimal(2014);
        annual.setDataYear(val2);
        System.out.println("Annual 2 : "+ annual2.toString());

        Annuals annual3 = new Annuals();
        annual.setDateCalculated(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.NET_INCOME);
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(7373.0));
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2015));

        Annuals annual4 = new Annuals();
        annual.setDateCalculated(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        annual.setType(InvestConstants.NET_INCOME);
        annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(4596.0));
        annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2016));

        //annualsList.add(annual);
        annualsList.add(annual2);
        annualsList.add(annual3);
        annualsList.add(annual4);
        System.out.println("Net Annuals List: Creating Company: "+annualsList.toString());
        return annualsList;
    }
```

Comment: You only call `setWhatever` on the first `annual`. You never call those methods on `annual1`, `annual2`, or `annual3`.

Comment: thanks! I didn't catch that

Answer (score 4):

```
Annuals annual1 = new Annuals();
annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2014));
annual.setValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(4009.0));
annual.setType(InvestConstants.TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING);
```

You are creating new instances named `annual1`, `annual2` and so on - but only ever modify `annual`.

Answer (score 2):

You're reusing always the same variable `annual`.

Pay attention to your code, after creating a new instance of `Annual` and assigning the instance to a variable `annual1` or `annual2` you're reusing the old variable `annual`.

```
Annuals annual1 = new Annuals();

annual.setDataYear(BigDecimal.valueOf(2014));
```

Comment: Thanks! Man, simple stuff... I didn't catch it.